# What is the etymology behind "-j" indicating bzip2 for tar?

Tags: tar, bzip2

What is the etymology behind "-j" indicating bzip2 for tar?

Comment: There probably isn't a specific reason for why `-j` was used. `-b` and `-B` were already taken, so all obvious choices were impossible. Maybe it's because bzip2's developer is Julian Seward...

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to SU - here is the [faq].  While this is a computer related question, it is off topic to post questions inviting discussions or otherwise don't have a technical solution.

Comment: @Paul Do you know of any stackexchange sites that would be appropriate for this question?

Comment: @MaxNanasy: In any case, this is a question that only the people involved in the decision can answer con authority. You could try the [GNU tar mailing list](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/#maillists).

Comment: Sorry @MaxNanasy I don't.  The switch was introduced in 2000 by Paul Eggert.  Perhaps he is still around to ask? http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/tar/tar/ChangeLog?view=markup&content-type=text%2Fvnd.viewcvs-markup&revision=1.97